# $f(x)f(\frac{1}{x})=1\hspace{1 em}\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R^*}\to\mathbb{R^*}$ that satisfy $$f(x)f(\frac{1}{x})=1\hspace{1 em}\forall x\in\mathbb{R^*}$$

I only found that every function $f(x)=x^n, n\in\mathbb{N^*}$ is a solution. Can you find all the solutions to this?

Comment: How about $f(x) = x^{-n}, \ x \in \mathbb{N}^*$?

Comment: Hint: There is no relation tying $f(2)$ and $f(3)$ together. There are many more such functions. You need to use the same $n$ for $2$ and $1/2$, but $2$ and $3$ can use a different exponent.

Comment: But, did you search the site? This sounds like a question we might have already handled.